# Flower (plants) recognizion

Tags: google-api, face-detection, face-recognition, google-vision, android-vision

Can Mobile Vision API be used us order to detect flower (plants) species?
Do you have other recommendation?
I have tried looking to several other API's but not sure what to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Mobile Vision API from Google can detect **just a few most popular genera** (species). I have tested Vision API a few month ago, but it's not really useful for this narrow use-case; also it needs to have a visible flower on the photo (not just leaves/stem).

Let me suggest specialized plant identification API instead: https://plant.id/api According to this independent study https://academic.oup.com/aobpla/article/12/6/plaa052/5910496 it is the most accurate plant identification software on the market (significantly better than Google Lens).

The demo client runs on https://plant.id so everybody can test the accuracy. Also the company gives a free trial to new clients.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Vision API can be used to detect Flower/Plant.

It generates good result. 
It shows plan flower name and also it gives Plant/Flower family name as well.

Comment: Hi @TechFanatic can you please share the docs link where google vision api is used for flower recognition

Comment: @Love-Kesh You have to use Label detection for detection of Flower/Plants. Link - https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/label-tutorial

Comment: How do I retrieve the flower name from the results?
For Cyclamen image I have got the following result for example:
[0] => Flower
    [1] => Flowering plant
    [2] => Plant
    [3] => Petal
    [4] => Purple
    [5] => Cyclamen
    [6] => Leaf
    [7] => Herbaceous plant
    [8] => Bellflower family
    [9] => Groundcover

Thanks,
Yair

Answer (score 0):

Nope, sorry :(

Mobile Vision API can for now only detect faces and scan barcodes.

I can hardly imagine that there is any API for detecting which kind of flower it is, based just on the picture of it :(